# Azure python eventhub triggered function showing binding error

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an azure function which is triggered by eventhub and the code looks like this:

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(events: func.EventHubEvent):
    print(events.get_body())
```

The triggering is working properly. But I am getting an error every time I try to display the event or group of events.

```
Exception binding parameter 'events'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'Object') uses Json.NET serialization.
1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'Object' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or    
2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Error parsing Infinity value. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

.

My `function.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "eventHUBENV",
      "connection": "EventHubConnection",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to convert as string and as json etc but this error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

- you will have to decode the string using the `decode()` function which will decode the message
- You will also have to pass the encoding algorithm here we have `UTF-8`
- Here I have also converted the string to Json object

mycode:

```
from  typing  import  List
import  logging
import  json
import azure.functions as  func

  
  

def  main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):

    for  event  in  events:
        jsonobject = json.loads(event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        logging.info(jsonobject.get("message"))
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

output:
[image]

Here first I am displaying the string and then value of the message tag in the Json object